# Any general name for functions with open or closed pre-image?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Suppose for a binary function we assume that the pre-image sets, 
$C_0 = f^{-1}(0)$ and $C_1 = f^{-1}(1)$, are either open or closed. 
Is there any general name for such functions?

Comment: If $f$ is binary and $f^{-1}(1)$ is open (resp. closed), then $f$ is called an "[indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of an open (resp. closed) set."

Comment: Thanks, if you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.